# Fail to send multiuser email

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

Case: i would like to Blind Copy TO multiuser [send mail]

[image: GM][image: HRM]

method 1: using vector [Fail] with error message say is null

```
var maildoc:NotesDocument = database.createDocument();
maildoc.replaceItemValue("Form", "Memo");
maildoc.replaceItemValue("Subject", "STATUS OF APPLICATION FOR REQUEST AN EMAIL");
session.setConvertMime(false);
var z:java.util.Vector = new java.util.Vector();

var vw:NotesView = database.getView("(Notifier Setting)");
var doc:NotesDocument = vw.getFirstDocument();
if (doc != null) {
    z.addElement(doc.getItemValue("HRM"));
    z.addElement(doc.getItemValue("GM"));
}
maildoc.replaceItemValue("BlindCopyTo",z)
```

method 2: using array [Fail] with error message replaceitemvalue cannot used array

```
var z=[];
var vw:NotesView = database.getView("(Notifier Setting)");
var doc:NotesDocument = vw.getFirstDocument();
if (doc != null) {
    z.push(doc.getItemValue("HRM"));
    z.push(doc.getItemValue("GM"));
}
maildoc.replaceItemValue("BlindCopyTo",z)
```

method 3:Using string [no person in blindcopy list]

```
maildoc.replaceItemValue("BlindCopyTo",doc.getItemValue("HRM")+","+doc.getItemValue("GM"))
```

May i know which way is correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function NotesDocument.getItemValue() returns a (java.util.)**Vector**, so if you use addElement or push on z (as in methods 1 and 2), it just adds the whole vector instead of its children.

Your code should work if you use method 1 and replace

```
z.addElement(doc.getItemValue("HRM"));
z.addElement(doc.getItemValue("GM"));
```

with

```
z.addAll(doc.getItemValue("HRM"));
z.addAll(doc.getItemValue("GM"));
```

---

PS: Mark Leusink has written a nice SSJS class for mail sending which is available in [OpenNTF XSnippets](https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=create-html-mails-in-ssjs-using-mime).